# reading excel file with fill( )

Tags: r, readxl

I am re-adjusting someone's else code which goes like:

```
china <- read_excel("Data/China.xlsx",range = "A5:J62") %>% 
  fill(X__1)
```

I don't know what fill(X__1) means here. And I receive an error:

```
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'X__1' not found
```

I installed all packages (readxl, tidyr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the help files

```
?tidyr::fill
```

> Fills missing values in using the previous entry. This is useful in
>   the common output format where values are not repeated, they're
>   recorded each time they change.

I.e. it takes the first non-missing value in `X__1` and repeat it through all missing values.

The error you receive means there is no 'X__1' column to fill values into.

Comment: thanks for the speedy response!
What does X__1 stand for? A name of the column?

Comment: @hypatia when reading excel files, R generates column names for vectors with data but without given name, starting with `X__1`, `X__2` and so on. So a good first step would be to check `names(china)` after importing.